# How to get a list (or vector) of tibbles

Tags: r, dplyr

In Python, I could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series([1,2,3])
s2 = pd.Series([4,5,6])
combo = [s1, s2]
```

I want to do something similar in R. I tried this:

```
library(dplyr)

tbl1 <- tibble(1:3)
tbl2 <- tibble(4:6)
combo <- c(tbl1, tbl2)
```

But that destroys the dplyr data structure and just creates a list of lists.

How do I get a list (or vector) of tibbles?

Comment: Change it to `list` instead of `c` `list(tbl1, tbl2)`.

Comment: Do you want list of tibbles or only one tibble of vectors? `tbl1 <- c(1:3);tbl2 <- c(4:6)` and `combo <- tibble(tbl1, tbl2)`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `data.frame/tibble/data.table` are all `list` with added `class` attributes.  When we do the `c`oncatenation, it removes those `class` attributes and results in a simple `list` of `vector` i.e. columns.  If we want to preserve the `class`, wrap with `list`

```
combo <- list(tbl1, tbl2)
```

or as a named `list`

```
combo <- dplyr::lst(tbl1, tbl2)
```

Answer (score 2):

As @akrun said you are looking for the list object, not an atomic vector (constructed via `c()`). You can further name the list objects, access them, and merge them as so:

```
# create datalist
datalist <- list(
   "tbl1" = tibble::tibble(a = 1:3, b = letters[1:3]),
   "tbl2" = tibble::tibble(a = 4:6, b = letters[4:6])
 )

# access tbl from list
datalist[["tbl1"]]

# merge into single data.frame/tibble
combined <- dplyr::bind_rows(datalist, .id = "table_name")
```